# Creating a function that returns true if element is in unordered_set, how to deal with templates?

Tags: c++

I have this unordered_set:

```
std::unordered_set<Category, CategoryHash, CategoryEqual>
```

I have to do this:

```
if (allowTheseCategories->find(message.category) != allowTheseCategories->end())
```

in order to find if an element exists in the `unordered_set`

I wanted to write a function that returns true or false if element exists in unordered_set, but I quickly figured out that it'd have to deal with types:

```
template <typename T, Typename U, typename V>
bool unorderedSetHasElement(std::unordered_set<T, U, V>& unorderedSet, T element) {
    return unorderedSet->find(element) != unorderedSet->end()
}
```

and calling this function would not be pratical, since I'd have to do:

```
if (unorderedSetHasElement<Category, CategoryHash, CategoryEqual>(...))
```

Is there any way to create a simple function that accepts `unordered_set`? Or is there a way to extend `unordered_set` to have this function?

Comment: Most commonly, you just use the (already existing) `count` method of `unordered_set` -- it returns 1 if the element is in the set and 0 if it is not.  So you just use `if (allowTheseCategories->count(message.category))`...

Comment: Tried, have you? Could you present an example program (a minimally short one) in which you would have to explicitly list template arguments when calling that function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find that you do not have to include the template parameters every time you call a templated function. Your compiler should be able to deduce the types automatically. The following code is valide c++ if you fill in the `...`'s.

```
std::unordered_set<Category, CategoryHash, CategoryEqual> my_set(...);
if (unorderedSetHasElement(my_set, ...)){
  ... 
}
```

EDIT: You may be interested in writing the function for any associative container. Here is a simple version.

```
template <typename Container, typename ContinerKey>
bool Contains(Container& cont, ContinerKey key)
{
    return cont.find(key) != cont.end();
}
```

Note in this version I am ignoring the template parameters of the container. You do not have to have them, but the compiler will blow up with lots of unreadable errors if you do not use it correctly. For more complex versions you may want to use type traits to determine if the type is an associative container.

Comment: what do you mean by the second `...`? It'd just be the element itself

Comment: Exactly, I just don't know what that element is.